# How To Integrate payment gateway in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Can any one help me in payment gateway integration in php with sample code any payment methods

Help Please

Comment: You should add some code and show your research effort, be more specific, and perhaps read the FAQ section in the first place.

Comment: Please google first before posting questions.

Comment: Read this http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

Comment: You should atleast describe which payment gateway you want to integrate as each implementation is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many payment gateways available. Like [CCAvenue](https://www.ccavenue.com/) etc. You want to select one from them and they will send you the integration code.